# TypeScript: function `includes` must take same type parameter

Tags: typescript

In **TypeScript**, function `Array.Prototype.includes` requires me to pass in the same type as in the original array. But I'm thinking isn't the whole point of using `includes` to find out if a key of arbitrary `string` type exists in an array with known type?

Consider code below:

```
type CONFIG_MODEL = {
  URL: string;
  Protocol: string;
  Port: number;
  Encrypted: boolean;
}

const ALLOWED_KEYS: (keyof CONFIG_MODEL)[] = ['URL', 'Protocol'];

function setup(configs: { [key: string]: string }) {
  Object.keys(configs).forEach(configKey => {
    if (ALLOWED_KEYS.includes(configKey)) {
      // do something
    }
  })
}
```

[Link to **TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg8gOQGIEkDiB9AsnAIgUQBkoBeKAbwFgAoKKAVQCVCAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwDmAbhp0AClwD2wSQGNJAGzadegkbShjJXYGz4BXALYAjCF3V18fWV3DAIAEzbHJiiAEM%206gL40a8vk4oAEFCQjgAdXxcDABpfABNAGU2AAoAawgQSQAzWERUTBwCQgBKAG0AXVIocoByJkI6gBooOolpOUU6yvUaHP1rYB5JPg4IYH0wVICcngF2NnJazJBlbn4BSvXVAShvUopRKDhjACsIWWAAOlX2GdG5hdLrnO18d1kACwe%20J9isqQAHxHDR0Hh5VKhcJRGLxZLXfiyBT6BwQe6zeYAkClQ5UMF0KAAeiJUAckg4kkMEy%20m2OdF8GgONG8QA)

TypeScript throws me an error when using `includes`, stating:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'keyof CONFIG_MODEL'

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a known bug/"feature" https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. That's relieving

Answer (score 1):

Just try to iterate over allowed keys instead of whole object keys
Example:

```js
type CONFIG_MODEL = {
  URL: string;
  Protocol: string;
  Port: number;
  Encrypted: boolean;
}

type AllowedKeys = Array<keyof CONFIG_MODEL>;

const ALLOWED_KEYS: AllowedKeys = ['URL', 'Protocol'];

const hasProperty=<Obj,Prop extends string>(obj:Obj,prop:Prop):obj is Obj & Record<Prop,string>=>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,prop);

function setup(configs: { [key: string]: string }) {  
  ALLOWED_KEYS.forEach(elem=>{
    if(hasProperty(configs, elem)){
      // do smth with config
      const result = configs[elem] // ok
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I believe type casting here is a bad choice. It deadens all the benefits I get from using TypeScript. I KNOW the input `configs` is NOT of type `AllowdKeys`, so I believe casting it, misleads other developers.

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian. That's a nice workaround. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

The `as string[]` cast in the penultimate line here, just before `.includes`, also addresses the issue:

```
//type externally defined in original
type ClassicalElement = 'earth' | 'water' | 'wind' | 'fire'; 
const classicalElements = ['earth', 'water', 'wind', 'fire'] as ClassicalElement[];
const isClassicalElement = function(
    possibleElement: string
): possibleElement is ClassicalElement {
    return (classicalElements as string[]).includes(possibleElement);
}
```

Playground links: [with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IJYGMFwKJwgWwgDtgoBeKAcggQCdgALSqAHyoHcFgJbm3L2qIgBM+VAGapaESgG4oAegUQAHt1pEscEFGERJRCMKhCoAe1qoA5kKwBYAFDozRJKXSIUGLLgLFgSORQANrUdIyUADQcXDxRHEKi0ZSS0pQAulDIsJ5omDh4hCTB6bKOzq6kqEjwyHk+hf5B4gCuROjAqC4AFGBmXgBGeL5FwABcUG6WRFYAlBN9g8ONJCaBtV75I00A3o4AkErYtLQW5kRQhmpQcEIQEwCCtFYto+biUKCQVFNCVszVS5mUh1ayaIbQYBmKBgOgIQjqd6fcDQSgbeoFPwkSgAOgO0mALQ0UA8oK2KwCOKEHhaeiQvX6aAh2xIszKDgAvo4gA) and [without](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IJYGMFwKJwgWwgDtgoBeKAcggQCdgALSqAHyoHcFgJbm3L2qIgBM+VAGapaESgG4oAegUQAHt1pEscEFGERJRCMKhCoAe1qoA5kKwBYAFDozRJKXSIUGLLgLFgSORQANrUdIyUADQcXDxRHEKi0ZSS0pQAulDIsJ5omDh4hCTB6bKOzq6kqEjwyHk+hf5B4gCuROjAqC4AFGBmXgBGeL5FwABcUG6WRFYAlBN9g8ONJCaBtV75I00A3o4AkNLALRpQ3R513gV+JIHZU0JWJbMAdEIeLXpIvf1oQxDbEizMoOAC+QA) error.