# Array.prototype.includes give me "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'." error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

The type of `keys` is `string[] | number[]`, derived from `ID` type.
The type of `id` is `ID`. Try to check if `keys` includes the `id`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type DistributedArray<U> = U extends any ? U[] : never;
type ID = string | number;

function Comp() {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState<DistributedArray<ID>>([]);
    const id: ID = '1';
    keys.includes(id)

    return null;
}
```

TSC throws an error in `keys.includes(id)` statement.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

From a JS perspective, the code is fine.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsDcAUDzAE8wVACLBCMKMABG+SgBMAglCgoBAHgCqAPjgBeOJrhIAHpQB28wnBTmBcAPyGA2gF04ALjjmkANyRQvILCcACSIvpwElLmAOZwAD7e+CDSAbw8dPjmGMAQ5nAAwkxgABQAlLg8cDVwaPkScM4A1kgChNjEMADSbYTuBkSk5JTqYtEyckhKKmrq4drapW7lvLV1DfDA8l7hkSwAjNzVta3tAHTAOQA2+PJIhKXb5Xzr7DD4UAXm+NfXvNQeEA)

version: TypeScript 4.5.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: function \`includes\` must take same type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190764/typescript-function-includes-must-take-same-type-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type ID = string | number;

function Comp() {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState<ID[]>([]);
    const id: ID = '1';
    keys.includes(id)

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You change the type, this is not what I want. The type `ID[]` is NOT equal with `DistributedArray<ID>` You can use `type IfEquals<T, U, Y=unknown, N=never> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;` to compare two types.